Why is MRS the gradient of the indifference curve times -1?
Why is the -1 necessary?
Is it because while the MRS is a ratio of Marginal Utilities which is positive so the MRS is also always positive, the gradient of the indifference is always negative, so the -1 is needed to balance out the signs?

This question is similar to: Does Varian define the MRS differently/ as negative?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/11187/42
